# How to make complex searches in django ? Use views or models?

Tags: django, django-models, search, django-views, full-text-search

I want to create a Job search page on my Django Application.

I'm now wondering what the best practice is on how to develop this.

Would it be better to do al the filtering in my views? Or should I do all the filtering in the models?

Answer (score 1):

There is no real best practice really in terms of this filtering and if any performance difference it would be very minimal.

It would come down to preference. You could create methods in the Model if this method will be called a multiple times throughout your project, other than this scenario I see no reason personally as to why you couldn't filter in your view if it is a bespoke, one-off query.

Hope this clarifies things for you.

Comment: Thanks @stackdon, clarifies it.
Couldn't we also create a utils.py file that contains the query code and reuse it in several views ?

Comment: You could do this, but creating a method for it in the model would be a better practice as you are calling the query regardless. Would definitely make for cleaner code.

Comment: Cleaner code would be to use a `utils.py` file if you are going to reuse a lot of the code

Comment: https://breadcrumbscollector.tech/stop-naming-your-python-modules-utils/